# Transform HTML table into XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am reading a book on XSL right now. There are plenty of resources on converting XML into HTML tables, but I can't find any resources on transforming HTML tables into XML. How can I achieve this? Do I need Xpath? Javascript? Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: In principle: use something like validator.nu to convert the HTML to XHTML, then do an XSLT transformation. The details will depend on the actual form of the input and desired output.

Comment: I'd use something like [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or its Java port [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to convert html to xhtml.